# Записать в регистр элемент массива

Tags: массивы, ассемблер

Мне необходимо записать в регистр ax третий элемент массива из 10 целых чисел,используя режим адресации по базе.Вот мой код,но он почему-то не работает.

```
.386
.model flat
extrn ExitProcess:PROC
extrn MessageBoxA:PROC
.data
mas dw 12, 2, 7, 3, 2, 0, 21, 9, 0, 16  ;массив 
len dw $-mas    ;размер массива в байтах
.code
start:
push 0h
mov bx,mas
mov ax,[bx+2]
call ExitProcess
end start
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
; не bx, так как используется 32-битная архитектура:
mov ebx, offset mas
; 4 - потому что индекс третьего элемента - 2,
; а размер элемента - 2 байта.
; Это не C, где добавление индекса увеличивает адрес
; на индекс*размер, здесь всё надо считать вручную:
mov ax, [ebx+4]
```

Comment: Ошибка компиляции offset pointer is 32-bit

Comment: offset or pointer*

Comment: Потому что вы работаете на 32-битной архитектуре, стало быть, адрес в 16-разрядный регистр загрузить не можете. Используйте `ebx`.

Answer (score 0):

`mov bx,mas` заносит в BX не адрес массива, а его первый элемент, используйте `lea bx, mas` или `mov bx, offset mas` (в зависимости от вашего ассемблера).

`mov ax,[bx+2]` - У вас размер элемента в массиве 2 байта (dw), следовательно смещение до 3-го элемента должно быть +4